Weird behaviour of IPv6 on our servers
I need help solving IPv6 issues on our servers. We currently have two servers—the original one will be turned off in the coming days, and we will switch to the new one. However, we've encountered a problem with IPv6 and since I'm not a network expert, I'm not sure how to handle it on my own. Both servers are running Proxmox with several containers. One of these containers is a webserver that I need to be accessible via IPv6.
IPv6 worked on the original server. We used the addresses:
XXXX:XXXX:0070:0000:0000:0000:0000:0020/64 (physical server - vmbr)
XXXX:XXXX:0070:0000:0000:0000:0000:0023/64 (container)
On the new server, I set the addresses:
XXXX:XXXX:0070:0000:0001:0000:0000:0071/64 (physical server - vmbr)
XXXX:XXXX:0070:0000:0001:0000:0000:0021/64 (container)
(I used 0001 instead of 0000 in the fifth block to differentiate the servers)
All addresses are within the XXXX:XXXX:0070::/64 range, which was assigned to us by our server hosting provider - same for both servers.
The gateway is set to XXXX:XXXX:0070:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 everywhere. The problem is that IPv6 works intermittently and is currently also problematic on the original server. I'm not sure if it was an issue on the original server before, but I think it wasn't.
Current behavior:

From my location, I can ping the physical server address on the
original server, but not the container's address.
From my location,
I can ping the container's address on the new server, but not the
physical server's address.
Pinging via
https://tools.keycdn.com/ipv6-ping from some locations does not work
while it does from others. It behaves in such a way that some
locations act like my local pings, while others are the exact
opposite — for example, what can’t be pinged from Frankfurt can be
pinged from Amsterdam and vice versa.
Connection tests to a testing
website via IPv6 https://ready.chair6.net sometimes indicate that
IPv6 is working and then again it isn't.
Neither server can ping any
of the IPv6 addresses of the other.

The only thing that occurred to me is that since we received the same range for both servers, maybe there's a conflict. I tried splitting the assigned range into two subnets by raising the mask from 64 to 80, but it didn’t help.
At this point, I am completely at a loss and would need advice on how to get it working. Is it okay that both servers use the same XXXX:XXXX:0070::/64 range? Do I need to change the settings for it to work?

So it was mistake by our hosting provider. They assigned same IPv6 subnet for both our servers and that created conflict in their routing.
